# variable in a grep command

Tags: bash, grep, pattern-matching

I want to extract a string from a text file MODIS_list.txt:

```
wget https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/archive/allData/6/MOD09GA/2018/062/ -O MODIS_list.txt
```

then to extract the name of MODIS file:

```
less MODIS_list.txt | grep -o -P '(?<=hdf">).*(?<=(MOD09GA.A2018062.h18v04.006)).*(?=</a>)'
```

which gives as output

```
MOD09GA.A2018062.h18v04.006.2018064030133.hdf
```

Let's say I would like to loop over more file changing, for example the date or the product.

```
prod_var=MOD09GA
prod_date=2018062
```

how can insert these two variables in the grep command!??

I tried in the following syntax but it does not work:

```
less MODIS_list.txt | grep -o -P '(?<=hdf">).*(?<=($prod_var.A$prod_date.h18v04.006)).*(?=</a>)'
```

Comment: Variables do not interpolate inside a single quoted string, use double quotes.

Comment: Which string do you want to extract from the MODIS_list.txt file (first step above)?

Comment: Do you mean `less  MODIS_list.txt` or (probably better) `cat MODIS_list.txt`?

Comment: @PierreFrançois Yes also `cat` can be used
I would like to extract the MODIS product that satisfy the pattern: _MOD09GA.A2018062.h18v04.006*_

Comment: Actually `grep` incredibly knows how to read a file all by itself; `grep 'regex' MODIS_list.txt`. See also [useless use of `cat`.](/q/11710552) (A useless `less` is, of course, priceless.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you want to execute is:

```
grep -o -P "(?<=hdf\\\">).*(?<=($prod_var.A$prod_date.h18v04.006)).*(?=</a>)" MODIS_list.txt
```

As wolfrevokcats says (but you need to know what they are speaking about), you have to change the single quotes into double quotes. The problem is that you have a quote after the string *hdf* which has to be escaped twice: once for the *shell*, and once for *grep*, but again you need to know what I am speaking about. Another solution that avoids the problem of escaping the quotes at the right side of 'hdf' is to use a '.' as follows:

```
grep -o -P "(?<=hdf.>).*(?<=($prod_var.A$prod_date.h18v04.006)).*(?=</a>)" MODIS_list.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Nevertheless, instead of using a monster regex, I suggest you to convert your html file into an xml file and to select the node you want by an xpath selection as follows:

```
tidy -q -f /dev/null -asxml --numeric-entities yes MODIS_list.txt | /usr/bin/xpath -q -e "//a[contains(@href,'$prod_var.A$prod_date.h18v04.006.2018064030133.hdf')]/text()"
```

Answer (score 1):

While grepping, you may concatenate constant string and variable.

```
Example: 
Dumpy:~ admin$ cat /tmp/file.txt 
user is john
user is pol
user is bob
user is mark
user is mike

Dumpy:~ admin$ export usrname='john'

Dumpy:~ admin$ grep --color 'user is '$usrname /tmp/file.txt 
user is john
```

Comment: There is no need to `export` the variable in this case. You should include double quotes around `$usrname` in order to allow the string to contain shell metacharacters. See also http://shellcheck.net/ for automaticalny diagnosing these and many other common errors and antipatterns.